# Expiry Alert before 30 days

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, alert

My application has to alert user about expiry of visa before 30 days or less. Once the visa is renewed, the user has mark it as renewed. I'm not sure how can I do it (use trigger with sql or method in c#)?

Comment: Do you have the option is SSIS on your SQL Server.

Comment: The easiest will be to call a SQL Server Sproc at the start of the application every time that checks for expiration of visa. Anything else would be over complicating it, I think.

Comment: I found folder ssis in Sql server 2008 . Is that what you mean ?

Comment: I think I would go with stored procedure but I don't know what to write and how can I deal with it?

Comment: How are you alerting the user's? If you are planning on sending out emails then I would just write a scheduled task that queries the database and sends out the appropriate emails.

Comment: No, I'm planning to show list of employees whom their Visa is about to expire in grid view.

Comment: If you plan to show the alert in your apps, then better create a stored proc that query list of employee having Visa expiry date equal or less than 30 days from current date. And at beginning of your apps, call that stored proc and display the list. Exactly as @logixologist suggested.

Comment: asp.net or windows forms? sql or mysql or oracle??? please show some effort when you ask for help

Answer (score 0):

Write a sql query to check the current date is less than 30 days of expire date. If so, show a alert. This query should run whenever the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
set @checktime=(select top 1 expiredate from yourtable where username='abc'order by uid desc)
select datediff(DAYS,@checktime ,Getdate()) as [expirydays];
```

From here you have number of expiry days and do your functionality

I hope you are searching for this